# Linear Algebra Valid Expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vectors

I'm taking a course on linear algebra and this was a challenge problem. I have no idea how to do this.

Suppose we have a list of n vectors and we place a binary product between each one. So, we place one between the first and second, second and third, and so on. There are three binary products: cross product, dot product, and product (scalar multiplication).

How many valid ways can we place binary products among the n vectors?

I'd imagine that there would be a pattern starting from little n, but not sure.

Comment: The way I see it, you can only ever have one dot product, the others can be whatever they like. But parentheses also matter for the result.

Comment: You can have more than one inner-product dot.,e.g, $(A\cdot B).(C\times D).(E\cdot F) $ (The uncentered dot is scalar multiplication). This is an interesting finite combinatorics problem. I think you should add that to your tags.

Comment: One minor clarification, please: do we allow scalar multiplication on the right? I.e., should this be considered valid? $$a.b\cdot c\times d$$(where I am using user254665's convention of a lower "." for scalar multiplication).